# ASP.NET Removing CSS

Tags: asp.net, css

I'm a noobie, so I try not to code if possible.  I was able to apply CSS by dragging the CSS file from the solution explorer to the web form.  However, I am not unable to remove the style.  I looked at the form property section, but no such option is offered.  Is there an easy way to remove the CSS without going to the code section?

Comment: It might prove hard in the future to use ASP.NET while trying not to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your visualization to `code` view and look for a `<link>`tag to your style file near the `<head>` tag. You should delete the entire tag.

Comment: Thank you. That would work.  Is there a dummy-proof way?  I try not to mess with the code if all possible.

Comment: If it works, please consider accept my answer. Well, you may look for the `Styles` toolbar to see the styles for a page. But I strongly reccomend you change `head` tags only in code. Try to be more attentive at the code and don't be scared with "dummy wrongs". The wrongs make you learn.

Answer (score 0):

You not find style on form maybe because your stylesheet is setted to the entire document.

I recommend you to learn at least the html and css basics, and not turn a hostage of drag drop.

Change to code and find  stylesheet tag, then remove it.

Take a look at [HTML](http://devdocs.io/html/) and [CSS](http://devdocs.io/css/) on devdocs.io